# Can a JQuery .each function be used to create a link for each li in a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, slider

I have been trying to create a sliding banner that has pagination buttons in the top right corner.  I am trying to write some JQuery that creates a button in the pagination for each list item (li) in the unordered list (ul).

I did some research and discovered .append for JQuery, which supposedly can create the HTML button links I need to populate the div that contains my pagination buttons.

**So my question is:** Can JQuery's .each be used to create a button link in the pagination div for each li in my slider ul?

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
$("div.brandtile ul.slider li").each(function () {
    $("div.button-wrap").append("<a href='#'>slide</a>");
});
```

I would greatly appreciate some help with this!  JavaScript/JQuery are still kind of new to me.  Thanks!

This is the HTML (I just included one of the li's, but there can be up to 5 in the ul):

```
<div class="brandtile">
    <div class="button-wrap"></div>
    <ul class="slider">
        <li style="background-image: url('/Image Library//brandtiles/brandtile1.jpg');">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>College and Career Readiness</h3>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to get it so the JQuery creates a link inside the div.button-wrap for each li in the ul.

Comment: Your code snippet looks too generic. Can you provide a sample html as well

Comment: Sorry, it should read `ul.slider` instead of `ul slider`

Comment: Have you tried it?  Looks like it should work . . . if you're having issues, what happens when you run your code?  Does it break?  JavaScript error (check the console)? etc.

Comment: @ernie I'm not getting any console errors, and nothing breaks.  It just doesn't add the html for the button links into the div.button-wrap

Comment: If you just need to add the links to the div, then your code should work perfectly.

Comment: Your code works fine (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDU4M/)).  Best guess at this point would be you're not actually running the jQuery each . . . what's the full <script> block look like?  And the error conditions you're seeing should be in the question, not in the comments . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I figure is the best way to do this is to cache the slider container element and then set references to the slideshow and the slideshow navigation.

For each `li` element in the slideshow append a `li` to the slider navigation and automatically generate the slide number and `href` value using the iteration value.

```
$(function(){
   var slider = $('#slider');
   var slideshow = slider.find('.slider');
   var slider_nav = slider.find('.slider-nav');

    slideshow.find('li').each(function(i){
        slider_nav.append('<li><a href="#' + ( i + 1 ) + '">Slide ' + ( i + 1 ) + '</a></li>');
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LeLkf/2/)**

Comment: Thank you so much.  This did the trick!  It needs a little further CSS styling, but I can handle that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#names-list li').each(function (i) {
 $(this).append("<a href='#'>slide</a>");
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/7ESKh/42/)**

Updated [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/7ESKh/43/)

Comment: The buttons don't go in the li.  They're supposed to go into the div.button-wrap that is in the same div.brandtile as the ul

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need the same no of links as of li inside the div.button-wrap. then your code is just perfect.

And second, if you need the link to be inside the li, then just use $(this) for current li and append the HTML in it.

```
$("div.brandtile ul slider li").each(function () {
    $(this).append("<a href='#'>slide</a>");
});
```